# How to download all the ophthalmic devices data from device classification end point in openFDA

Tags: data.gov, openfda, api, medical

The API call

https://api.fda.gov/device/classification.json?search=medical_specialty_description=%22ophthalmic%22

is returning (limiting) the number of records to 1 for ophthalmic devices data. I am trying to download all the records for ophthalmic data. I would appreciate if anyone could help me with the api call that can download all the records of ophthalmic data from device_classification end point.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `limit` and `skip` URL parameters described [here](https://open.fda.gov/api/).

Comment: hello Denis! Thanks for the answer. But, in my case, lets say, I need all the records for ophthalmic devices and I don't know the upper limit of the number ophthalmic device records. so, if I need all the records, should I query with certain limit (say 100) multiple times skipping the number of records I already got in previous queries each time, until I completely extract all the records?
Hypothetical query parameters: 1. limit=100, skip =0, 2. limit=100, skip=100, 3. limit =100, skip=200 ... n. limit =100, skip=max_records-100

Comment: You can find out the upper limit by inspecting `meta.results.total` of the returned JSON.